# .NET 7 Web API - Send JWT in API headers to gain access

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, asp.net-web-api, jwt

***Goal:***
Send JWT from frontend to backend to access TopicController endpoints.

I have a .NET 7 Web API connected to a React.ts frontend. Currently I am sending a JWT with an identity role claim to my frontend and am able to receive it, but am having difficulty processing the request on the backend to gain access to the API.

In the network I am getting two 204 responses from the desired endpoint, and two 302 responses, followed be to 405 responses from an endpoint generated by .NET I believe which checks if I am logged in.

Authorization works in swagger, though I do not have to send the JWT in the authorize section and it just works after logging in.

`API call in React:`

```
const getTopics = () => {
    const url = API_ROUTES.TOPICS_GET_ALL_TOPICS;
    fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `bearer ${jwt}`
      }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(topicsFromServer => {
      setTopics(topicsFromServer);
    })
    .catch((error => {
      console.error(error);
    }))
  }
```

`Login method in auth controller (to be refactored once I am able to utilize jwt correctly):`

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("/account/login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginDTO userLogin)
        {
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userLogin.Email, userLogin.Password, true, false);
            if (!result.Succeeded)
                return BadRequest(400);

            ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(userLogin.Email);
            string token = await CreateToken(user);

            LoginResult resultResponse = new LoginResult
            {
                succeeded = true,
                Data = new List<object> { token
                }
            };

            return Ok(resultResponse);
        }
```

`Create Token method in auth controller:`

```
 private async Task<string> CreateToken(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            IList<Claim> claims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                _configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value!));

            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    claims: claims,
                    expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                    signingCredentials: creds
                );

            var jwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
            return jwt;
        }
```

`TopicController (To be accessed only when user is logged in and has user role):`

```
namespace SdeResearch.Api.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "User")]
    public class TopicController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly SdeResearchDbContext _db;

        public TopicController(SdeResearchDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("/topic/get-all-topics")]
        public async Task<List<Topic>> GetTopicsAsync()
        {
            return await _db.Topics.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

`Cors policy in Program.cs:`

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CORSPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
    });
});
```

`AddAuthentication and AddAuthorization:`

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Issuer").Value!,
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Audience").Value!,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value!)),
        };
    });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
```

Any and all assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could understand you need to attach account to the context.
It's a three step process.

**Step 1: Create class CustomJwtHandlerMiddleware**

```
public class CustomJwtHandlerMiddleware
    {

        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public CustomJwtHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            var token = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault()?.Split(" ").Last();

            if (token != null)
                await AttachAccountToContext(context, token);
               
            await _next(context);
        }

        private async Task AttachAccountToContext(HttpContext context, string token)
        {
            try
            {
                var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

// handle token validation as per requirement
// key for symmetric key
                    tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    // set clockskew to zero so tokens expire exactly at token expiration time (instead of 5 minutes later)
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                }, out SecurityToken validatedToken);

                var jwtToken = (JwtSecurityToken)validatedToken;

                var accountId = jwtToken.Claims.First(x => x.Type == Constants.UserId).Value;

                // attach account to context on successful jwt validation from database
                context.Items["Account"] = // call to database to attach account;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // do nothing if jwt validation fails
                // account is not attached to context so request won't have access to secure routes
            }
        }
    }
```

**Step 2: Define Middleware extension**

```
public static class MiddlewareExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Use Jwt Hanlder Middleware
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="builder">Application builder instance</param>
        /// <returns>Application Builder</returns>
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseCustomJwtMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<CustomJwtHandlerMiddleware>();
        }
    }
```

**Step 3: Finally, add to pipeline in configure before `app.UseRouting()`**

```
app.UseCustomJwtMiddleware();
```

You can get the value from context using below code

```
    public class CurrentUserService : ICurrentUserService
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public CurrentUserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public ApplicationUser AppUser => (ApplicationUser)_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Items["Account"];
    }
```

Thanks !!!

Comment: I think I may be to new to understand this entirely and be able to configure it appropriately with .NET 7 Identity. Thank you for your answer though, it appears I need to link the token to the database context.